# Visualizing Orbits and Transitivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm having trouble "visualizing" orbits and transitivity.

So starting with an example, if I have the group $G=S_4$ acting on a non empty set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ I know that for example, the stabilizer of the element $2$, represented $G_2$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, because intuitively, if $2$ 'stays put', the other three element $1,3$ and $4$ can be permuted and thus there are 6 permutations of $\{1,3,4\}$.  Thus I know

$$G_2=\{1_{S_4},(1 3),(14),(34),(134),(143)\}$$

Now I'm trying to understand orbits.  Orbits are equivalence classes.  Basically, I think that I'm looking at all 24 permutations acting on an element in $A$.  So, if $\sigma\cdot i=\sigma(i)$, I'm looking for all permutations that send any element to a particular place in the permutation.  So, the orbit of $S_4$ containing 2 would then be

$$\{(24),(234),(1342),(1423),(13)(24),(142)\}$$

I'm pretty sure this is wrong.  These are elements of $S_4$ while my action is suppose to be into the set $A$

How do I visualize the appropriate orbits?  How can I view the action that is occurring in my mind so that these misunderstandings don't occur?  The question regarding transitivity also holds, since I need to understand orbits before understanding transitivity.

Comment: An orbit of an element $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the set $\{g\cdot x:g\in G\}$, which in this case equals $G=S_4$. In this case this action is said to be "transitive." A more illuminating example would be if you looked at some restricted action of $S_4$, say instead the subgroup $S_3$ fixing 4, then the orbit of 2 under $S_3$ would be $\{1,2,3\}$. 

In fact, try to show that for any action of $G$ on a set $X$, the size of $G$ equals the size of the stabilizer of any $x\in X$ times the orbit of $x$ under that action.

Comment: I think the big misconception here is that orbits are elements of the set being acted upon (unlike stabilizers, which are subsets of the group doing the acting, as you are aware).

Comment: so the action of every element from $G$ on a particular element in $A$ is transitive if we get $A$ back.  Otherwise it's just the elements that we get from the action.  As an example, if $T_3=\{1_{T_3},(12),(14),(24),(124),(142)\}$ (fixed 3) then the orbit of $3$ under $T_3$ would be $\{3\}$ and the orbit of say $2$ under $T_3$ is $\{1,2,4\}$?

Comment: Yes your example is exactly right, perfect! The phrasing of the first sentence seems a bit out of the ordinary to me, but I think you're saying the right thing. (My version is something like,  "if we let each $g \in G$ act on a particular $x \in X$ and the orbit is all of $X$, the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I'm trying to understand orbits.

Great! Let's find an example that will illustrate what orbits are. Note that the usual action of the permutation group $S_4$ on the set $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ is, orbit-wise, rather boring. This is because, for example, the orbit of $2$ under $S_4$ is
$$
\text{orb}(2) = \{\sigma (2) \,|\, \sigma \in S_4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}.
$$
In other words, there is only one orbit in $A$ under the action of $S_4$.

Now for an interesting example. Let $G$ be the group of rotation acting on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. The orbit of the point $0 = (0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ under $G$ is simply $\{0\}$. However, the orbit of a non-zero point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at the origin and containing $x$. (Can you see why?)

In this case, the set of all orbits is precisely the set of all circles centered at the origin, together with $\{0\}$. These circle are uniquely determined by a non-negative radius, and therefore the set of all orbits can be identified with $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

> How do I visualize the appropriate orbits?

I believe you ask how to visualize them in your mind and get an intuitive feeling for it. You can think of a group $G$ acting on $A$ as a set of invertible transformations on $A$. For instance, $A$ could be bread dough, with $G$ acting on $A$ by folding (or careful unfolding). If you place a seed in the dough, all the places the seed can go by folding and unfolding is precisely the orbit of the seed under $G$.

If you always fold the dough in the same upward direction, then the seed won't be able to move left and right and will be contained in a plane.

If you add more transformations to $G$ and mix the dough like crazy, then the seed will be able to go everywhere and you'll only have one orbit.

**In short:** The orbit of the seed $s$ under the action of $G$ is the set of all the places where $s$ can end up after being pushed around by the transformations in $G$.

Comment: I kind of visualized $\mathbb{C}$ and as an equivalence class, $\{z\in \mathbb{C} | |z|=k, k\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\}$, which is how i originally thought they were called orbits.  But for the permutation example I was just struggling to see how they worked.  I liked the bread example.  Thank you.